# JSONDATA : simple jsondata example for android

Tags: android, json

i'm new to jsondata, i need simple example for this jsondata. Please anyone give me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some nice example to deal with JSON.

[First](http://laurentszyster.be/less4j/javadoc/org/less4j/JSON.html)

[Second](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/)

[Third](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)